# Listing GCS bucket blobs from Cloud Function in the same project

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to list files in a bucket from a Google Cloud Function **in the same project.**

Right now, my code for the Cloud Function is

**main.py**

```
from google.cloud import storage

def my_function(event, context):
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    blobs = storage_client.list_blobs("my_bucket")

    for blob in blobs:
        print(blob.name)
```

**requirements.txt**

```
google-cloud==0.34.0
```

The error I'm getting is

> from google.cloud import storage ImportError: cannot import name 'storage' from 'google.cloud' (unknown location)

I was under the impression that `google-cloud` would be pre-loaded on the machines running the Cloud Function but it seems like this is not the case.

I have tried:

1. Reading the Google [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#code-samples) which is where the code comes from
2. Reading other questions here, namely [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840511/google-cloud-import-storage-cannot-import-storage) (this one suggested that `google-cloud` is not pre-loaded which is why I added it to the `requirements.txt`) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840511/google-cloud-import-storage-cannot-import-storage) (but I think there is a way to do this without setting `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`, as I'm calling from within the same project). Also read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53347006/reading-data-from-cloud-storage-via-cloud-functions) one but the approved answer's code looks like mine, which isn't working.

How can I list the files on the bucket?

Comment: That's a strange error.  It's not the usual `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'foo'` error you get when a module isn't installed.  Googling a bit, that error seems to come up when you're trying to import a module from your own source tree and you don't quite have it right.  I'm not sure how this applies to your project or Google Cloud in general.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[The google-cloud module (as is) is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud/). Last version is from 2018.

You need to specify *just* google-cloud-storage in your requirements.txt, like this:

```
google-cloud-storage>=1.31.0
```

Both pypy and the [google-cloud-python github page](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python#google-cloud-python-client), say you need to import *just* the modules for the service you will use.

As today (sep 2020), when you install just google-cloud-storage, it ends up installing google-cloud as a depency but there is no need to use it or import it from your code.

Also, remember that the service account that executes the cloud function must have the 'storage.buckets.list' IAM permission.

Comment: Very usefull, it's solve my problem in my project gcp  when i deploy my cloud function

Answer (score 0):

The `google-cloud` dependency contains all the common element of Google Cloud client library. But it doesn't contain all the libraries for all the GCP product.

Therefore, you have to include the client library for the CLoud Storage

- https://pypi.org/project/google-cloud-storage/

You can remove the `google-cloud` dependency because it is automatically included in the `google-cloud-storage` one