# I need help to create a Function in Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

```
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import io

def procesar_excel(event, context):

  bucket = event['bucket']
  blob_name = event['name']

  blob = bucket.get_blob(blob_name)
  content = blob.download_as_string()

                  # Leer el archivo Excel

                df = pd.read_excel('content')

                # Lista con el orden deseado de las columnas

                nuevo_orden = ['Fecha_Carga', 'Periodo_Carga', 'Email', 'Id_Nino', 'Id_Persona',   'Nombre_Nino', 'Apellido_Paterno_Nino', 'Apellido_Materno_Nino', 'Rut_Nino', 'Nombre_Persona', 'Apellido_Paterno_Persona', 'Apellido_Materno_Persona', 'Rut_Persona', 'Relacion', 'Profesion', 'Tipo', 'Fono', 'Celular', 'Id_Centro', 'Nombre_Centro', 'Zona', 'Comuna_Centro', 'Nivel', 'Jornada', 'Comuna_Domicilio', 'Comuna_Trabajo', 'Fecha_Ingreso_Vitamina', 'Fecha_Ingreso_Centro', 'Fecha_Avance_Nivel', 'Fecha_Retiro', 'Estado', 'Canal', 'Empresa', 'Rut_Empresa', 'Tipo_Cliente', 'Grupo_Empresa', 'Rut_Grupo_Empresa', 'Id_Sala', 'TAG', 'Id_Nino_Centro', 'Estado_Aux']

                # Reordenar columnas

                df = df[nuevo_orden]

                df["Fecha_Carga"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Fecha_Carga"])

                df

                # Cambiar formato

                df["Fecha_Carga"] = df["Fecha_Carga"].dt.strftime("%d-%m-%y")

                df.dropna(subset=['Email'], inplace=True)
                
                df = df.sort_values(by='Email', ascending=True)
                
                df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
                
                # Crear diccionario para mapear emails
                email_map = {}

                    # Recorrer dataframe
                for index, row in df.iterrows():
                    mail = row['Email']
                    nivel = row['Nivel']
    
                    # Si no está en el diccionario, agregar a Nivel1
                    if mail not in email_map:
                        email_map[mail] = {'Nivel1': nivel}
        
                    # Sino, verificar si está en Nivel2
                    elif 'Nivel1' in email_map[mail] and 'Nivel2' not in email_map[mail]:
                        email_map[mail]['Nivel2'] = nivel
    
                    # Sino, agregar a Nivel3
                    else:
                        email_map[mail]['Nivel3'] = nivel

                # Crear nuevo dataframe         
                nuevo_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(email_map, orient='index')
                
                nuevo_df = nuevo_df.reset_index().rename(columns={'index': 'Email'})
                
                df = df.drop_duplicates(subset='Email')
                
                df = pd.merge(df, nuevo_df, on='Email')
                
                df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
                                
                # Obtener la fecha y hora actual
                now = datetime.datetime.now()

                # Formatear la fecha y hora actual como string
                timestamp = now.strftime("%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")

                # Crear el nombre del archivo con la fecha y hora actual
                filename = f"Base Tag 31.7-procesada2_{timestamp}.xlsx"

                # Exportar a Excel


                df.to_excel(filename, index=False)
                self.label.setText("Archivo modificado y guardado en:\n" + path)

  # Subir archivo resultado a Cloud Storage
  nuevo_blob = bucket.blob('resultado_'+timestamp+'.xlsx')
  #nuevo_blob.upload_from_string(df.to_excel(), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
  
    with io.BytesIO() as output:
        writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output, engine='xlsxwriter')
        df.to_excel(writer, index=False)
        writer.save()
        nuevo_blob.upload_from_string(output.getvalue(), 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet')
  
  return f'Done!'
```

*I tried to accommodate the bucket but I understand that the bucket detects the file name when I choose it, I don't know how to get the response file. *

*I have created the Bucket in Cloud Storage
And I already uploaded the file I understand that when a file is uploaded the selected bucket looks for that file itself. Or does it need to be called by the script?*

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: The function could not be implemented....I dont know how to see why is the error

Comment: Cloud function with cloud storage finalize trigger runs immediately when you upload any object to the corresponding bucket. It looks like you are not creating Cloud storage instance but trying to access the contents directly through bucket name which does not work.  Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53347216/20239914)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are trying to retrieve the file from the bucket when it is created, do some processing and you want to achieve this using Cloud Function?

Firstly, GCS buckets do not do,"When a file is uploaded the selected bucket looks for that file itself". I highly suggest that you read the docs about how it can be achieved using Cloud Functions [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/storage#gcloud). You can trigger the Cloud Function automatically whenever a file is uploaded to the bucket.

```
gcloud functions deploy your_cloud_function_name \
--entry-point=my_function \
--trigger-event-filters="type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized" \
--trigger-event-filters='bucket=name_of_bucket' \
```

The above command is a minimal example (with limited arguments) of how your function deployment looks like.

- `your_cloud_function_name` is the name of the cloud function that you want to deploy
- `my_function` is the name of the python function that you want to execute, so in your case, something like "procesar_excel"
- `type=google.cloud.storage.object.v1.finalized` is the condition of how the function will be triggered. In this case, it will be triggered when a new object is created/uploaded into the specific bucket that you tell it to watch. More triggers can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/tutorials/storage)

The following code snippet shows how the file which triggered the Cloud Function can be pulled from the bucket to do some processing. I've included some print statement to help you understand what happens with the Metadata.

```python
# do the imports
import functions_framework
from google.cloud import storage
import pandas as pd

# Triggered by a change in a storage bucket
@functions_framework.cloud_event
def my_function(cloud_event):

    # get the metadata of the cloud_event
    data = cloud_event.data
    event_id = cloud_event["id"]
    bucket_name = data["bucket"]
    file_name = data["name"]
    timeCreated = data["timeCreated"]
    file_path = f"gs://{bucket_name}/{file_name}"
    print(f"Event ID: {event_id}")
    print(f"Cloud Function has been triggered due to change in the Bucket: {bucket_name}")
    print(f"Cloud Function has been triggered due to the file: {file_name}")
    print(f"Cloud Function has been triggered at: {timeCreated}")
    print(f"Complete path of the file is: {file_path}")

    # Instantiate a storage client
    storage_client = storage.Client()

    # Get the bucket and blob object
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(file_name)

    # Download the file contents
    file_contents = blob.download_as_bytes()
    
    # read the content of the excel file as a pandas dataframe
    df = pd.read_excel(file_contents)
    # your processing
    #...
```

"Internally, Cloud Functions uses open-source libraries called Function Frameworks that wrap user functions within a persistent HTTP application." Read more about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/function-frameworks).

Also, Github link to the python functions-framework can be found [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-python)